See keywords used by Google Ads campaign on Google analytics or Googe Ads dashboard
Is it possible to see the keywords taped by the users that triggered the display of the Google Ads?
I have created some "intelligent" campaigns, that kind of campaign lets Google choose the keywords that will make the ads display.
And nowhere in the Google Ads or Google Analytics dashboard I can see the keywords chosen by Google.
On the Traffic Acquisition (GA) I can the campaign name, but not the actual keywords.

Any ideas?
Thanks

If you have linked your Google Ads account to your Google Analytics account you will find this data under "Advertising > Planning > Google Ads". See documentation https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12930957. I guess you can also build an explore report with the dimensions and metrics your are looking for.

Thanks. I found it. But when I added "Session Google Ads keyword text" or "Session Google Ads query" in dimensions. it says no data available. But with "Session Google Ads campaign" I got data...
